# Building Android 2.2 in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: android, build, compilation, osx-lion

I want to build Android 2.2 for Mac OS X Lion, I initialized build environment and fetched the source code from android repository as mentioned in their site. I installed jdk 1.5 also. Everything went fine expect for an error regarding libSDL.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libSDL_intermediates/libSDL.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SDL_GetError", referenced from:
      _sdl_logerr in sdlaudio.o
      _skin_window_resize in window.o
      _skin_surface_lock in surface.o
      _skin_surface_create_argb32_from in surface.o
      _skin_surface_create_slow in surface.o
      _skin_surface_create_fast in surface.o
```

I think there is a problem in building libSDL for 64 bit architecture. Is there any way to force the entire android build to 32 bit arch?

Comment: Could you please tell us what java version you have currently? As Android 2.2 works on my lion perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://www.bango29.com/go/blog/2011/building-android-gingerbread-cyanogenmod-7-1-for-nexian-journey-mac-os-x-lion) for an answer on step 13. It's because the make failed to compile codes from the Emulator.